# @helper in App_Code not seen after publication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a helper method that I would like to share across multiple views like this:

```
@helper DoSomething()
{
    <h1>Something</h1>
}
```

I've saved that in a file called PMHelpers.cshtml in my app_code folder, and can run it locally on my dev box with a simple method call:

```
@PMHelpers.DoSomething()
```

And I get the desired result. When I try to publish to a Win2008R2 server I get the following error message:

```
 CS0103: The name 'PMHelpers' does not exist in the current context
```

Is there some special setting that I have to do in the WebDeploy process to get this to work? I really like declarative helpers as they are much easier to look at than helpers made with the TagHelper class.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Build Action on my cshtml page was set to "none" I set it to "content" and it worked like a charm.